# Tree shaking in NextJS includes all of node_modules package even if not using it all

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, lodash, next.js

Below is a screen shot of my package size from Next JS. What I want to point out is the `react-color` components under `node_modules`. I am importing them this way:

`import { GithubPickerProps, GithubPicker, AlphaPicker } from 'react-color';`

But you see it includes all the things I'm not using such as `photoshop.js`, `sketch.js`, etc.

How do I get it not to bundle the things I'm not using with tree shaking?

I did notice that `import { debounce } from 'lodash';` imported all of `lodash` but `import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';` reduced the package size by 200kB.

[image]

Comment: I tried, `Cannot find module 'react-color/GithubPickerProps'.` It's not a thing. Also, I think it should be able to tree shake from the data given.

Answer (score 13):

In order for the tree-shaking to work properly `react-color` should add `module` property to the `package.json` which will point to esm version of the lib.

Since it doesn't have it, you will need import directly.

Before:

```js
import React from 'react'
import SketchPicker  from 'react-color'

class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <SketchPicker />
  }
}
```

[image]

After:

```js
import React from 'react'
import SketchPicker  from 'react-color/lib/Sketch'

class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <SketchPicker />
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is just a workaround and cannot be applied everywhere. For example, lodash in your report still contains all unused code. I need to know what needs to be done to make tree shaking work for every library, including those which are dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: I told you what you need to do, contact the lib author, and request esm files.

Comment: for lodash read this https://www.azavea.com/blog/2019/03/07/lessons-on-tree-shaking-lodash/

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, I did notice that import { debounce } from 'lodash'; imported all of lodash but import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'; reduced the package size by 200kB. I stopped using react-color though..

Comment: I would like to open issue for the lib, so the maintainer will be aware of it.

Comment: The answer above covers the issue, in that, CJS files aren't tree-shakeable, **but** they're compatible across a wide variety of browsers. Therefore, you'll want to import components directly from the library. ESM, which is tree-shakeable, is still relatively new and while NextJS decided to handle ESM syntax, outside of NextJS, it's not well supported as of yet. And, on that note, you can work-around lodash by installing the components standalone npm package (like [lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce)), which should reduce the size even more.